# Binding to a new instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to figure out how to create a new instance of an object without breaking any XAML bindings. Right now all I'm working with is an `ObservableCollection` which I'll call:

```
Container.MyClass.MyCollection
```

In my ViewModel (with INPC implemented via Kind of Magic):

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Collection
{ 
    get { return Container.MyClass.MyCollection; } 
}
```

In my View:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Collection.Count}" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

So, if I try to get a 'fresh' instance of my class, I can call this and have the bindings remain intact:

```
public void WorkingSomewhatFreshInstance()
{
    Container.MyClass.MyCollection.Clear();

    Container.MyClass.MyCollection.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "Test1" });
    Container.MyClass.MyCollection.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "Test2" });
}
```

However, if I call this method:

```
public MyClass BrokenFreshInstance()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();

    myClass.MyCollection.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "Test1" });
    myClass.MyCollection.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "Test2" });

    return myClass;
}
```

and then:

```
Container.MyClass = Initialize.BrokenFreshInstance();
```

The bindings no longer update. Is there any way to use a new instance of an object and have XAML bindings remain intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the View to refresh the binding to the new instance by calling the PropertyChanged on the Observable:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set 
    {
        _collection = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Collection");
    }
}
```

You will need to assign the collections to this property to trigger the event:

```
 Collection = Container.MyClass.MyCollection;   //This will trigger the PropertyChangedEvent
 ...
 Container.MyClass = Initialize.BrokenFreshInstance();
 Collection = Container.MyClass.MyCollection;   // Trigger again..
```

Or you can raise the change manually by doing:

```
Container.MyClass = Initialize.BrokenFreshInstance();
RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Collection");
```

Comment: Your first solution worked. However, since I'm using Kind of Magic, I didn't even have to manually call `RaisePropertyChanged`; I just had to assign a field and a setter. Is there any way of getting around that and still be able to simply return the value from the getter? Either way, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Also, the property is in a different ViewModel than the command, so I don't think your second answer will work for me.

Comment: Scratch that, once the value is manually assigned, auto-properties work just fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then I would go for the first approach. You can maybe achieve it by raising it manually `RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Collection");`. Howerver I would need to see more code to really understand how the parent classes that contain the collections work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire a `PropertyChanged` event for `Collection` if the instance returned by the property changes.